# Installing virtio drivers on windows server 2016

Tags: windows, networking, virtualization, windows-server-2016, drivers

I am trying to install virtio drivers on a VPS I bought and i installed a windows server on via an unintended method. But I am stuck... I don't have an internet connection to the server. So I cant download the drivers. I only have a noVNC window / Iframe that I can interact with. I have a couple of ways to get the drivers installed but they may be dumb.

I could convert the .sys file to base64 and type it over.. or use the built-in copy-paste tool in the noVNC but that is really buggy and corrupts text.

I could use a different way of transferring but i have no idea how...

Please help!

Comment: Why do you need this? I mean, virtio drivers only are usable when the VM is configured to provide (emulate) virtio "devices". If your system is working now, without virtio drivers, it could only be if the platform doesn't emulate such devices, and therefore virtio drivers will be useless. Only if the installation of drivers is accompanied with reconfiguration of the virtualization platform they'll be useful.

Comment: Well, I am running windows in a VM hosted by a company. But the drivers for the RedHat virtio ethernet adapter are not installing because i dont have a connection

Comment: Do you have a way to connect a virtual CD image to this system? Because [this](https://fedorapeople.org/groups/virt/virtio-win/direct-downloads/stable-virtio/virtio-win.iso) is all what you need.

Comment: I don't, I only have a copy-paste window that allows 100 characters at a time so i am thinking I convert the.sys file to base64 and transfer it and then convert it back? Or is that my 16 year old brain thinking wayyy out of the box

Comment: This is absolutely insane way of doing things. I'd refuse and require *normal* way of doing my work. I mean, I don't expect everything should be presented on the bowl with the blue rim, but I won't fix a chair leg by gluing 100 toothsticks together either.

Answer (score 2):

Ask your ISP to install the drivers. Because it might have conflicts which they need to verify otherwise you break your VPS.